# How get currently IP address of RabbitMQ in Java?

Tags: java, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-rabbit

I have a connectionFactory (org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection) with list of addresses

```
    @Bean(name = "mainConnectionFactory")
    @Primary
    public ConnectionFactory mainConnectionFactory() {
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
        String addresses = rabbitmqHost_main + ":" + rabbitmqPort_main + ", " + rabbitmqHost_reserve + ":" + rabbitmqPort_reserve;;
        connectionFactory.setVirtualHost(rabbitmqVirtualHost_main);
        connectionFactory.setUsername(rabbitmqUsername_main);
        connectionFactory.setPassword(rabbitmqPassword_main);
        connectionFactory.setAddresses(addresses);
        return connectionFactory;
    }
```

Periodically my app automatically reconnects to one of the servers. How can I get an IP address of current server in Java?

Answer (score 0):

Can use something similar to get the hostname from the server in which the program is running

```
try {
            InetAddress addr;
            addr = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            hostname = addr.getHostName();
        } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
            LOGGER.error("Hostname can not be resolved");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the currently connected host using the connection (the connection factory maintains a single shared connection).

```
@Bean
public ApplicationRunner runner(CachingConnectionFactory mainConnectionFactory) {
    return args -> {
        try (Connection connection = mainConnectionFactory.createConnection()) {
            System.out.println(connection.getDelegate().getAddress());
        }
    };
}
```